# Regular expression to match non-negative integers in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I seem to get it to work with the following regexp by [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
@^(?:[1-9][0-9]*)|0$@
```

Yet it's weird that it matches `-0`, considering there are no `-` allowed at all in the regexp. Why?

What's more weird is that if you switch the parts divided by `|`:

```
@^0|(?:[1-9][0-9]*)$@
```

It matches all negative integers such as `-2` and `-10`, etc.

What am I missing here? Any better regexp for non-negative integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex: `@^(?:[1-9][0-9]*)|0$@`

1. says match those number that start
   with `1-9` followed by any digit `0` or
   more times **OR**
2. match those numbers that end with `0`.

Clearly `-0` satisfies condition 2 so you get the match.

The regex you need is: `@^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$@`

which matches `0` or any other `+ve` number without leading `0`. If leading 0's are allowed then all you need to check is if the input contains digits for which you can use: `^\d+$` as Mark mentions.

Also why not just do a simple check like:

```
if($input >= 0)
 // $input is non -ve.
```

Comment: You could also check for the *begins with zero* case with a lookahead, e.g. `/^(?!0)\d+$/D` (Don't forget the `D` modifier!)